# Remove array symbol inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Don't ask me how but I've ended with `[[[THIS]]]`

I need to convert `[[[THIS]]]` into `[[THIS]]`, don't ask me why.

Comment: Then you don't ask us how. ;)

Comment: Some code would be useful.Like what have you tried already. Or where do you get this?

Comment: This should do the trick: `[[[THIS]]][[+[]][+[]]]` ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fufu9nqy/))

Comment: why you want to do this

Comment: Is this given to you as string? or an array object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
var array = [[[THIS]]];
array[0][0] = array[0][0][0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just take the first element.

```js
var array = [[[42]]];
array = array[0];
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is given to you as an Array object, then Nina's answer should suffice.

Otherwise, if this is a string then

```
var input = "[[[THIS]]]";
var output = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse( input  )[0]); //assuming you want to turn it back to string again. otherwise JSON.parse( input  )[0] should suffice

console.log(input);
```